# How to create Hybris Impex for import from given .xml code

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex, hybris-data-hub

I am somehow trying reverse engineering. I was wondering how can I create an impex from code below. I am quite new at this, so I wounder if I am on the right track. Mainly i have problem in the **Header** section of the Impex.

**So the main question is, how to create the two Hybris impex-es from given data.**

```
<collectiontype elementtype="BoxLink" code="BoxLinkList" autocreate="true" generate="true" type="list"/>
 
<itemtype code="BoxLink" autocreate="true" generate="true"
   jaloclass="com.ggcorporate.core.jalo.BoxLink">
   <deployment table="BoxLink" typecode="10226"/>
   <custom-properties>
       <property name="catalogItemType">
         <value>java.lang.Boolean.TRUE</value>
       </property>
       <property name="catalogVersionAttributeQualifier">
         <value>"catalogVersion"</value>
       </property>
       <property name="uniqueKeyAttributeQualifier">
         <value>"code"</value>
       </property>
       <property name="catalog.sync.default.root.type"><value>Boolean.TRUE</value></property>
 <property name="catalog.sync.default.root.type.order"><value>Integer.valueOf(8)</value></property>
   </custom-properties>
   <attributes>
      <attribute type="java.lang.String" qualifier="code">
         <description>Short unique code for link box</description>
         <persistence type="property"/>
         <modifiers optional="false"/>
      </attribute>
      <attribute type="CatalogVersion" qualifier="catalogVersion">
         <description>Catalog version for link box</description>
         <persistence type="property"/>
         <modifiers optional="false"/>
      </attribute>
      <attribute type="localized:java.lang.String" qualifier="link">
         <description>Link name</description>
         <persistence type="property"/>
      </attribute>
      <attribute type="java.lang.String" qualifier="url">
         <persistence type="property"/>
         <modifiers optional="false"/>
      </attribute>
   </attributes>
</itemtype>


<itemtype code="LinkBoxComponent" extends="SimpleCMSComponent" generate="true" autocreate="true" 
   jaloclass="com.ggcorporate.core.jalo.LinkBoxComponent">
 <deployment table="LinkBoxComponent" typecode="10227"/>
 <attributes>
   <attribute type="localized:java.lang.String" qualifier="title">
      <description>Title for link box</description>
      <persistence type="property"/>
   </attribute>
   <attribute type="BoxLinkList" qualifier="boxLinkList">
      <description>List of links</description>
      <persistence type="property"/>
   </attribute>
 </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

Do i need to do something like this?

```
INSERT_UPDATE BoxLink;code[unique=tru];catalogVersion;link;url
;?;?;?;?;?
```

And this?

```
INSERT_UPDATE code[unique=true];title;link;url
;?;?;?;?
```

Comment: any relevance to change question header and body of the question content?

Comment: It seems the edit invalidates the answer given. If you have a new question, please just ask a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on ItemType below impex should work.

```
$contentCatalog=<<catalogName>> 
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=$contentCatalog:Staged] 

    INSERT_UPDATE BoxLink;$contentCV[unique=true];code[unique=true];link[en];url
    ;;boxcode;/test;www.test.com
    
    
    INSERT_UPDATE LinkBoxComponent;uid[unique=true];$contentCV[unique=true];title[en];boxLinkList(code)
    ;linkboxcomp1;;link box title;boxcode,boxcode1
```